# JQuery is not giving feedback

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small school project. I am trying to check if a casino name is registered in MySQL database. If the name not exist the small green tick(glyphicon-ok) should show from the bootstrap framework. When I type in a name in the form now, I am not getting any feedback from my JQuery at all. So my specifik question is:

- Is my syntax in my JQuery correct?
- Is it not correct to use the same "createcasino" for id and name in the input type?

I hope somebody can help me?

html:

```
<form id="casinoForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal fv-form fv-form-bootstrap" action="createcasino.php" novalidate="novalidate"><button type="submit" class="fv-hidden-submit" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></button>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
       <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Casino Name</label>
       <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="createcasino" id="createcasino" data-fv-field="createcasino"><i class="form-control-feedback" data-fv-icon-for="createcasino" style="display: none;"></i>
          <small class="help-block" data-fv-validator="notEmpty" data-fv-for="createcasino" data-fv-result="NOT_VALIDATED" style="display: none;">The Casinoname is required</small><span id="casinocheck" class="help-block"></span</div>
   </div>
</form>
```

createvalidation.js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#createcasino').keyup(function() {
    var usercheck = $(this).val();
            $('#casinocheck').html('');                     /* !!!!Koden finder ikke glyphicon !!!!!*/
            $.post("casinocheck.php", {casino_name: usercheck } , function(data)
            {
            if (data.status == true)
            {
            $('#casinocheck').parent('div').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');

            } else {
            $('#casinocheck').parent('div').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
            }
            $('#casinocheck').html(data.msg);
            },'json');
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#casinoForm').formValidation({
        message: 'test',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        createcasino: {
                message: 'test',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Casino name is required'
                    }
                }    
        }  
    )};
)};
```

casinocheck.php

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include 'dbconfic.inc.php';

if(isset($_POST['casino_name']) && $_POST['casino_name'] != '')
    {
        $response = array();
        $cas = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['casino_name']);
        $sql  = "SELECT * FROM casinos WHERE name='' ";
        $res    = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        $count  = mysqli_num_rows($res);
        if($count > 0)
        {
            $response['status'] = false;
            $response['msg'] = 'Casino Already Exist.';
        }
        else
        {
            $response['status'] = true;
            $response['msg'] = 'Casino available.';
        }
         echo json_encode($response);
}?>
```

createcasino.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


// Selecting Database
include 'dbconfic.inc.php';

if(isset($_POST["createcasino"])) {
    $cas = trim($_POST["createcasino"]);


    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO casinos(name) VALUES(?)");

        $stmt->bind_param('s', $cas);

            // execute prepared statement 
                if ($stmt->execute()) { // tjek om udført:
                    $success = true;
                }
                    // luk statement
                $stmt->close();

                // luk connection
                $mysqli->close();   
if($success) {
    echo "Insert Succesfull";
} else {
    echo "Failed" .  $stmt->error;
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: What is `casinocheck` here  `{casino_name: casinocheck}`? Maybe its `usercheck`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `keypress` event on form id instead of `textbox` id

```
$('#casinoForm').keyup(function() { // this id has to be your input box id and not your form id
```

Use `createcasino` for `keyup` event. It will then capture the data from text box.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="createcasino" id="createcasino" data-fv-field="createcasino">
```

So change it to : `$('#createcasino').keyup(function() {`

Also this has to change to:

```
$.post("casinocheck.php", {casino_name: usercheck } , function(data)
```

Also you are missing where in select query:

```
$sql  = "SELECT name FROM casinos";
```

Check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bsgxj5od/

Comment: Thank you a lot. I have changed the things you suggested now, and it absolutly make sence. Do you think there is more vital errors in my code? Still nothing happends. I am a little bit in doubt if the glyphicon is called at all.

Comment: @MadsKristensen is ur post method getting executed? `casinocheck.php` is getting called?

Comment: no actually not. When I hit create nothing is happening. I am just gonna update my code here. Update: The code is now updated.

Comment: @MadsKristensen have you included jquery js files?

Comment: I have included this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/o2sjkfu8/
       
But I actually get an error now, where it says: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" .. regarding the fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

Comment: @MadsKristensen you require to embed the fonts to the webpage.

Comment: Ah yes that is correct. It is just so weird, that it works on another page. Could it have something to do with that the form, is inside a <div class="modal fade"><form></form></div>? . I even tried to copy/paste your code, and it is still not working :-/ . Still nothing happends.

Comment: @MadsKristensen your exact code is working on JSFiddle!